# Java- adding a new row to a JTable in GUI

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a simple Java GUI which is displaying an empty table and a few buttons. I am now trying to add a listener to one of the buttons that will add a new empty row (with editable cells) to the table in the GUI.

I am using the following code to try and do this:

```
JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("'Add' button pressed. ");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Site", "Application", "Entity"});
        System.out.println("--- ActionListener added to 'addBtn' ---");
    }
});
```

However, when I click the button, I am getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It says that this is occurring on the following line:

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{"Site", "Application", "Entity"});
```

I am not sure why I'm getting this exception... I've created a new `Object[]` array, and given it three elements... but I'm not trying to access those elements (or any elements that don't exist)...

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you add those columns explicitly, like so `model.addColumn("Column");`

Comment: No- I haven't added any columns as such- just a row with the column headings. Presumably then, I should get rid of that row, and add the three columns as you've indicated instead?

Comment: Just given that a try- and it doesn't do what I was hoping... What that does is add another three columns next to the three I already have there (giving me a total of 6 columns). What I want to do, is add a new row, underneath the row that I already have. The row that I already have is just there to contain the column headings, and I now want to add a row of empty cells underneath, which the user will populate themselves.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the table/columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jEntityFilterTable.getModel();

Vector row = new Vector();
row.add("Site");
row.add("Application");
row.add("Entity");
model.addRow(row);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried giving it a go, but I get the same `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as I was getting before- this time on the line: `model.addRow(row);`...